# Can't take input from a terminal

Tags: solaris

We are `migrating` from an `HPUX` system to a `solaris 64`. When we try `more` command `without arguments` in `HPUX` it `waits for stdin` (just like "cat" command), but in `solaris` there is a different result:

/usr/xpg4/bin/more

```
Can't take input from a terminal
```

(trying /usr/bin/more show the usage section:"Usage: /usr/bin/more [-cdflrsuw] [-lines] [+linenumber] [+/pattern] [filename ...].")

Don't know if it's a terminal configuration problem, environment value or another configuration trouble (or this is just normal and we can't change it).

The `TERM` environment is set to `vt100` (try with xterm too without success).

Is it possible to change the `behavior` from `more` command for `waiting stdin` in solaris?

ps. Forgot to say we connect with a PUTTY in ssh mode.

Comment: Can you just get used to the other implementation? Do you use `more` in scripts that you will need to convert, do you need to update user manuals or are you just curious?

Comment: Hi Walter, it's a client requirement. They want the same behavior they had before. And yes, I'm curious too...

Comment: I have done a lot LCM migrations, and usually they want a 1-to-1 migration. No extra work, no discussions, no change of manuals. However, there are always slight technical changes. `uname` will not respond HPUX. `more` works different. Small ksh-implementation differences. Performance. Admin tools. Try to discuss the requirements: they should be functional not technical. And still some functional changes might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

(Converting my comment to an answer, because this is (in my opinion) the solution.)

It's unreasonable for anyone to expect that their system will react exactly the same following a platform migration. This is one of those times that the time spent trying to "make X system look like Y system" is a huge waste of time. The client either needs to deal with the change, or move back to the HP-UX platform. I dealt with this for years. If you fudge the Solaris system, you're propagating bad habits and causing future sys admins a hellish task of supporting that setup.

If the customers requirements and lack of ability/motivation to perform any updates is that strong, migrating to a new platform should never be an option. As I said before though, if you modify the tools on the Solaris box to emulate an HP-UX, you've created a hybrid one-off environment that will be a nightmare in months/years to come. Hiring a "Solaris admin" in the future will mean nothing, if all of the commands work like an HP-UX. (Can you tell I feel strongly about this?)